# How can I check for first letter(s) in string in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

I'm writing test file, but I can't get it pass second test, here:

```
def translate(word)
    if word.start_with?('a','e','i','o','u')        
      word << "ay"  
    else        
      word << "bay"
    end
end
```

Is `start_with?` the right method to do the job?

```
describe "#translate" do

  it "translates a word beginning with a vowel" do
    s = translate("apple")
    s.should == "appleay"
  end

  it "translates a word beginning with a consonant" do
    s = translate("banana")
    s.should == "ananabay"
  end

  it "translates a word beginning with two consonants" do
    s = translate("cherry")
    s.should == "errychay"
  end
end
```

EDIT:
My solution is not complete.
My code pass first test only because I was able to push "ay" to the end of word. What I'm missing to pass the second test is to remove the first letter if its consonant, which is "b" in "banana".

Comment: Why is the first letter removed if it's a consonant? Your code doesn't do that, hence the test don't pass.

Comment: Is the `if` expression you posted the body of the `translate` method? How the test fails?

Comment: @toro2k Yes I have def translate(word) ... end

Comment: How can you expect `"banana"` to change into `"ananabay"`, or even `"cherry"` to change into `"errychay"` by adding either `"ay"` or `"bay"`?

Comment: As far as I see all the tests end with "ay". Whenever a vowel occurs in the string, the string to the left of that is cut and appended at last of the string and then "ay" is added. Am I thinking wrong here? Just let me know, while I write the logic for translate method in the answer part.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Pig-Latin method translation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13498688/pig-latin-method-translation)

Answer (score 5):

You can do this also:

```
word << %w(a e i o u).include?(word[0]) ? 'ay' : 'bay'
```

Using a Regex might be overkill in your case, but could be handy if you want to match more complex strings.

Comment: When i run rake i got error.

  1) #translate translates a word beginning with a vowel
     Failure/Error: s = translate("apple")
     TypeError:
       can't convert true into String

Comment: This approach relies on the changes to the String class in Ruby 1.9+ (which everyone should be using now, but just in case…)

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are removing the first character if the word starts with a consonant too, so:

```
if word.start_with?('a','e','i','o','u')
  word[0] = ''
  word << 'ay'
else 
  consonant = word[0]
  word << "#{consonant}ay"
end
```

Comment: Sorry, if I'm not wrong, the output would be "cherrycay" in the third test. But the test case expects that to be "errychay". On second look the first test also fails here. The output from your code would be "ppleay", but test case expects "appleay".

Answer (score 1):

`word << word[0].match(/a|e|i|o|u/).nil? ? 'bay' : 'ay'`

Answer (score 1):

Your code means:
if word start with ('a','e','i','o','u') add "ay" at the end
else add "bay" at the end.

Second test will be "bananabay" and not "ananabay" (with b as first letter)

Comment: I got first test pass by: word << 'ay' if word.start_with?('a','e','i','o','u'). But i can't get second one to pass, I always have the letter b at the beginning

Comment: That's because your translate function does not remove it. Try to think about what the translate function needs to do in english first. Then try and write it in ruby

Answer (score 1):

```
def translate(word)
  prefix = word[0, %w(a e i o u).map{|vowel| "#{word}aeiou".index(vowel)}.min]
  "#{word[prefix.length..-1]}#{prefix}ay"
end

puts translate("apple")   #=> "appleay"
puts translate("banana")  #=> "ananabay"
puts translate("cherry")  #=> "errychay"
```

Comment: I would go for this solution instead of mine. It looks more rubyish...Single liner :) .

Answer (score 0):

The below piece of code passes all the tests...

```
def translate(word)
  if word.start_with?('a','e','i','o','u')
    word<<'ay'
  else
    pos=nil
    ['a','e','i','o','u'].each do |vowel|
      pos = word.index(vowel)
      break unless pos.nil?
    end
    unless pos.nil?
      pre = word.partition(word[pos,1]).first
      word.slice!(pre)
      word<<pre+'ay'
    else
      #code to be executed when no vowels are there in the word
      #eg words fry,dry
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Figured I'd share my first contribution!
Good luck!

```rb
def method(word)
  word[0].eql?("A" || "E" || "I" || "O" || "U")
end
```